# How to extend a continuous function from domain open in $H^k$ to a domain open in $R^k$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Assume $f:U\mapsto V$ is continuous and of class $C^r$, and $U$ open in $H^k$ but not $R^k$. How do I extend $f$ to $g:U'\mapsto V$, $g$ is also continuous and of class $C^r$, $U'$ is open in $R^k$, and $g$ agrees with $f$ on $U$?

Comment: What is $H^k$ ?

Comment: It's the upper half-space in R^k.

Answer (score 1):

There is a general [Whitney extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_extension_theorem) for extension of smooth functions from closed subsets of $\mathbb R^k$. But in your case a [higher order reflection](http://calculus7.org/2014/07/27/higher-order-reflections/) will do the job, and in a quite explicit way.It is  the same for $k=1$ as for general $k$, so I'll state it in one dimension: 
$$f(-x) = \sum_{j=0}^r a_j f(2^{-j}x) \tag1$$ 
where the coefficients $a_j$ are chosen so that for $m=0,\dots,r$ we have 
$$(-1)^m = \sum_{j=0}^r a_j 2^{-jm} \tag2$$ 
The meaning of (2) is that every polynomial of degree at most $r$ is preserved by the reflection formula. Writing down the Taylor approximation to $f$ of order $r$, centered at a point of the reflection plane, you will see that the reflected function also satisfies it.